# Allocating VLAN to partition

Tags: virtual-machine, aix, vlan

Forgive me if my terminology if off, here -- I'm fairly new to AIX.

I have an AIX server (6.1) running VIO, with two client partitions (e.g. CLIENTA and CLIENTB).  The two partitions are running on an SEA bound between a single physical interface (ent0) and a virtual (eth4).  Both partitions have this SEA as their first interface within the IVM (these appear within each partition as ent0).

This was fine in our back-office staging environment; however, once deployed to our datacentre, it is intended that the CLIENTA partition will only be accessible from one VLAN (112), the CLIENTB partition will only be accessible from another VLAN (113) and the VIO will only be accessible from a management VLAN (12).  We already have the firewall and switching in place to support these VLANs and maintain these boundaries for our existing equipment (mostly Windows/Linux).

Using a combination of articles ([1](http://powerwire.eu/masterclass-creating-an-etherchannel-adapter-for-resiliency-with-vio-server), [2](http://www.torontoaix.com/vio-how-to-s/how-to-work-with-vlan-using-vios)), I have done the following:

- Using `cfgassist`, I have created an Etherchannel (ent9) across two of the physical interfaces (ent2 and ent3) as a basic NIB, with ent2 as active and ent3 as backup.
- I have then created the SEA on top of the Etherchannel (ent10), using `mkvdev -sea ent9 -vadapter ent5 -default ent5 -defaultid 1`
- I have then created the two client VLANs with `mkvdev -vlan ent10 -tagid 112` and `mkvdev -vlan ent10 -tagid 113` (creating ent11 and ent12, respectively).

Now, when examining the 'Ethernet' tab for the CLIENTA and CLIENTB partitions in the IVM, it looks like I can assign either ent0 or ent9 as an adapter.  For now, I have left ent0 as the first adapter and ent9 as the second.

On each client partition, I can see ent0 and ent1, and I have access on our staging LAN using ent0.  I'm trying to get the access working through the ent1 interface (i.e. using the Etherchannel/VLAN trunk) but traffic is not going through.

On each client partition I have created a VLAN device (using `smitty`), with base adapter ent1 and tagid 112 (for CLIENTA) or 113 (for CLIENTB).  This created ent2.  I have used mktcpip to assign an IP, subnet mask and gateway to the equivalent en2 device.  `netstat -nr` shows what I would expect it to, with my staging network on the en0 interface, and the regular network (and default route) on the en2 interface.

I am now testing by ping to both the outside world (8.8.8.8) and to/from another device on the 112 LAN and I'm getting nothing in either direction.

1. What am I missing which is preventing traffic from passing along the interface?
2. What is there to stop the end-user (once deployed) from making their own VLAN interface tagged 113 and accessing the other client's partition?

---

## Update: Command outputs

### VIO

```
$ entstat -all ent10
-------------------------------------------------------------
ETHERNET STATISTICS (ent10) :
Device Type: Shared Ethernet Adapter
Hardware Address: 98:be:94:02:1a:e2
Elapsed Time: 0 days 2 hours 55 minutes 50 seconds

Transmit Statistics:                          Receive Statistics:
--------------------                          -------------------
Packets: 1054                                 Packets: 16121
Bytes: 63240                                  Bytes: 1787781
Interrupts: 0                                 Interrupts: 16121
Transmit Errors: 0                            Receive Errors: 0
Packets Dropped: 0                            Packets Dropped: 0
                                              Bad Packets: 0
Max Packets on S/W Transmit Queue: 0         
S/W Transmit Queue Overflow: 0
Current S/W+H/W Transmit Queue Length: 0

Elapsed Time: 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 0 seconds
Broadcast Packets: 0                          Broadcast Packets: 2146
Multicast Packets: 0                          Multicast Packets: 11682
No Carrier Sense: 0                           CRC Errors: 0
DMA Underrun: 0                               DMA Overrun: 0
Lost CTS Errors: 0                            Alignment Errors: 0
Max Collision Errors: 0                       No Resource Errors: 0
Late Collision Errors: 0                      Receive Collision Errors: 0
Deferred: 0                                   Packet Too Short Errors: 0
SQE Test: 0                                   Packet Too Long Errors: 0
Timeout Errors: 0                             Packets Discarded by Adapter: 0
Single Collision Count: 0                     Receiver Start Count: 0
Multiple Collision Count: 0
Current HW Transmit Queue Length: 0

General Statistics:
-------------------
No mbuf Errors: 0
Adapter Reset Count: 0
Adapter Data Rate: 0
Driver Flags: Up Broadcast Running 
        Simplex 64BitSupport ChecksumOffload 
        LargeSend DataRateSet 

--------------------------------------------------------------
Statistics for adapters in the Shared Ethernet Adapter ent10
--------------------------------------------------------------
Number of adapters: 2
SEA Flags: 00000183
    < THREAD >
    < LARGESEND >
VLAN Ids :
    ent5: 2
Real Side Statistics:
    Packets received: 8060
    Packets bridged: 1054
    Packets consumed: 5807
    Packets fragmented: 0
    Packets transmitted: 0
    Packets dropped: 5807
    Packets filtered(VlanId): 1199
    Packets filtered(Reserved address): 5807
Virtual Side Statistics:
    Packets received: 0
    Packets bridged: 0
    Packets consumed: 0
    Packets fragmented: 0
    Packets transmitted: 1054
    Packets dropped: 0
    Packets filtered(VlanId): 0
Other Statistics:
    Output packets generated: 0
    Output packets dropped: 0
    Device output failures: 0
    Memory allocation failures: 0
    ICMP error packets sent: 0
    Non IP packets larger than MTU: 0
    Thread queue overflow packets: 0


        SEA THREADS INFORMATION

        Thread .............. #0
    SEA Default Queue #8 
    Queue full dropped packets: 0
    Queue packets queued: 0
    Queue average packets queued: 1
    Queue packets count: 19
    Queue max packets queued: 1

        Thread .............. #1
    SEA Default Queue #8 
    Queue full dropped packets: 0
    Queue packets queued: 0
    Queue average packets queued: 1
    Queue packets count: 713
    Queue max packets queued: 1

        Thread .............. #3
    SEA Default Queue #8 
    Queue full dropped packets: 0
    Queue packets queued: 0
    Queue average packets queued: 1
    Queue packets count: 5567
    Queue max packets queued: 1

        Thread .............. #4
    SEA Default Queue #8 
    Queue full dropped packets: 0
    Queue packets queued: 0
    Queue average packets queued: 1
    Queue packets count: 1074
    Queue max packets queued: 1

        Thread .............. #5
    SEA Default Queue #8 
    Queue full dropped packets: 0
    Queue packets queued: 0
    Queue average packets queued: 1
    Queue packets count: 6
    Queue max packets queued: 1

        Thread .............. #6
    SEA Default Queue #8 
    Queue full dropped packets: 0
    Queue packets queued: 0
    Queue average packets queued: 1
    Queue packets count: 681
    Queue max packets queued: 1
--------------------------------------------------------------
Real Adapter: ent9

ETHERNET STATISTICS (ent9) :
Device Type: EtherChannel
Hardware Address: 98:be:94:02:1a:e2

Transmit Statistics:                          Receive Statistics:
--------------------                          -------------------
Packets: 0                                    Packets: 16121
Bytes: 0                                      Bytes: 1787781
Interrupts: 0                                 Interrupts: 16121
Transmit Errors: 0                            Receive Errors: 0
Packets Dropped: 0                            Packets Dropped: 0
                                              Bad Packets: 0

Max Packets on S/W Transmit Queue: 0         
S/W Transmit Queue Overflow: 0
Current S/W+H/W Transmit Queue Length: 0

Broadcast Packets: 0                          Broadcast Packets: 2146
Multicast Packets: 0                          Multicast Packets: 11682
No Carrier Sense: 0                           CRC Errors: 0
DMA Underrun: 0                               DMA Overrun: 0
Lost CTS Errors: 0                            Alignment Errors: 0
Max Collision Errors: 0                       No Resource Errors: 0
Late Collision Errors: 0                      Receive Collision Errors: 0
Deferred: 0                                   Packet Too Short Errors: 0
SQE Test: 0                                   Packet Too Long Errors: 0
Timeout Errors: 0                             Packets Discarded by Adapter: 0
Single Collision Count: 0                     Receiver Start Count: 0
Multiple Collision Count: 0
Current HW Transmit Queue Length: 0

General Statistics:
-------------------
No mbuf Errors: 0
Adapter Reset Count: 0
Adapter Data Rate: 2000
Driver Flags: Up Broadcast Running 
        Simplex Promiscuous 64BitSupport 
        ChecksumOffload PrivateSegment LargeSend DataRateSet 

=============================================================
=============================================================

Statistics for every adapter in the EtherChannel:
-------------------------------------------------

Number of adapters: 2
Active channel: primary channel
Operating mode: Network interface backup mode

-------------------------------------------------------------

ETHERNET STATISTICS (ent2) :
Device Type: Gigabit Ethernet PCIe Adapter (e4145716e4142004)
Hardware Address: 98:be:94:02:1a:e2

Transmit Statistics:                          Receive Statistics:
--------------------                          -------------------
Packets: 0                                    Packets: 8060
Bytes: 0                                      Bytes: 898955
Interrupts: 0                                 Interrupts: 8060
Transmit Errors: 0                            Receive Errors: 0
Packets Dropped: 0                            Packets Dropped: 0
                                              Bad Packets: 0
Max Packets on S/W Transmit Queue: 0         
S/W Transmit Queue Overflow: 0
Current S/W+H/W Transmit Queue Length: 0

Broadcast Packets: 0                          Broadcast Packets: 1073
Multicast Packets: 0                          Multicast Packets: 5841
No Carrier Sense: 0                           CRC Errors: 0
DMA Underrun: 0                               DMA Overrun: 0
Lost CTS Errors: 0                            Alignment Errors: 0
Max Collision Errors: 0                       No Resource Errors: 0
Late Collision Errors: 0                      Receive Collision Errors: 0
Deferred: 0                                   Packet Too Short Errors: 0
SQE Test: 0                                   Packet Too Long Errors: 0
Timeout Errors: 0                             Packets Discarded by Adapter: 0
Single Collision Count: 0                     Receiver Start Count: 0
Multiple Collision Count: 0
Current HW Transmit Queue Length: 0

General Statistics:
-------------------
No mbuf Errors: 0
Adapter Reset Count: 0
Adapter Data Rate: 2000
Driver Flags: Up Broadcast Running 
        Simplex Promiscuous 64BitSupport 
        ChecksumOffload PrivateSegment LargeSend 
        DataRateSet 

Gigabit Ethernet PCIe Adapter (e4145716e4142004) Specific Statistics:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Additional Driver Flags: 
Entries to transmit timeout routine: 0
Link Status: Up
Media Speed Selected: 100 Mbps Full Duplex
Media Speed Running: 100 Mbps Full Duplex
Transmit and Receive Flow Control Status: Enabled
        XON Flow Control Packets Transmitted: 0
        XON Flow Control Packets Received: 0
        XOFF Flow Control Packets Transmitted: 0
        XOFF Flow Control Packets Received: 0
Jumbo Frames: Disabled
TCP Segmentation Offload: Enabled
        TCP Segmentation Offload Packets Transmitted: 0
Assigned Interrupt Source Numbers: 
        Bus interrupt level 0 : 255520
        Bus interrupt level 1 : 255521
Receive statistics for RXQ number: 1
        Number of receive packets: 8060
        Number of receive bytes: 898955
        Number of receive interrupts: 8060
        Number of receive bad packets: 0
        Number of receive packet drops: 0
        Number of RX mbufs allocated from system pool: 0
        Number of RX mbufs allocated from system pool for Jumbo: 0
        Number of system pool RX mbuf allocation failures: 0
        Number of rx_hog events: 0
        Receive TCP Segment Aggregation: Disabled
Transmit statistics for TXQ number: 1
        Number of transmit packets: 0
        Number of transmit bytes: 0
        Number of Unicast Packets: 0
        Number of Multicast packets: 0
        Number of Broadcast packets: 0
        Number of transmit packet drops: 0
        Number of transmit queue overflows: 0
        TCP segmentation offload packets transmitted: 0
        Maximum entries used on this transmit queue: 0

-------------------------------------------------------------
Backup adapter - ent3:
======================

ETHERNET STATISTICS (ent3) :
Device Type: Gigabit Ethernet PCIe Adapter (e4145716e4142004)
Hardware Address: 98:be:94:02:1a:e2

Transmit Statistics:                          Receive Statistics:
--------------------                          -------------------
Packets: 0                                    Packets: 8061
Bytes: 0                                      Bytes: 888826
Interrupts: 0                                 Interrupts: 8061
Transmit Errors: 0                            Receive Errors: 0
Packets Dropped: 0                            Packets Dropped: 0
                                              Bad Packets: 0
Max Packets on S/W Transmit Queue: 0         
S/W Transmit Queue Overflow: 0
Current S/W+H/W Transmit Queue Length: 0

Broadcast Packets: 0                          Broadcast Packets: 1073
Multicast Packets: 0                          Multicast Packets: 5841
No Carrier Sense: 0                           CRC Errors: 0
DMA Underrun: 0                               DMA Overrun: 0
Lost CTS Errors: 0                            Alignment Errors: 0
Max Collision Errors: 0                       No Resource Errors: 0
Late Collision Errors: 0                      Receive Collision Errors: 0
Deferred: 0                                   Packet Too Short Errors: 0
SQE Test: 0                                   Packet Too Long Errors: 0
Timeout Errors: 0                             Packets Discarded by Adapter: 0
Single Collision Count: 0                     Receiver Start Count: 0
Multiple Collision Count: 0
Current HW Transmit Queue Length: 0

General Statistics:
-------------------
No mbuf Errors: 0
Adapter Reset Count: 0
Adapter Data Rate: 2000
Driver Flags: Up Broadcast Running 
        Simplex Promiscuous 64BitSupport 
        ChecksumOffload PrivateSegment LargeSend 
        DataRateSet 

Gigabit Ethernet PCIe Adapter (e4145716e4142004) Specific Statistics:
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Additional Driver Flags: 
Entries to transmit timeout routine: 0
Link Status: Up
Media Speed Selected: 100 Mbps Full Duplex
Media Speed Running: 100 Mbps Full Duplex
Transmit and Receive Flow Control Status: Enabled
        XON Flow Control Packets Transmitted: 0
        XON Flow Control Packets Received: 0
        XOFF Flow Control Packets Transmitted: 0
        XOFF Flow Control Packets Received: 0
Jumbo Frames: Disabled
TCP Segmentation Offload: Enabled
        TCP Segmentation Offload Packets Transmitted: 0
Assigned Interrupt Source Numbers: 
        Bus interrupt level 0 : 255496
        Bus interrupt level 1 : 255497
Receive statistics for RXQ number: 1
        Number of receive packets: 8061
        Number of receive bytes: 888826
        Number of receive interrupts: 8061
        Number of receive bad packets: 0
        Number of receive packet drops: 0
        Number of RX mbufs allocated from system pool: 0
        Number of RX mbufs allocated from system pool for Jumbo: 0
        Number of system pool RX mbuf allocation failures: 0
        Number of rx_hog events: 0
        Receive TCP Segment Aggregation: Disabled
Transmit statistics for TXQ number: 1
        Number of transmit packets: 0
        Number of transmit bytes: 0
        Number of Unicast Packets: 0
        Number of Multicast packets: 0
        Number of Broadcast packets: 0
        Number of transmit packet drops: 0
        Number of transmit queue overflows: 0
        TCP segmentation offload packets transmitted: 0
        Maximum entries used on this transmit queue: 0

--------------------------------------------------------------
Virtual Adapter: ent5

ETHERNET STATISTICS (ent5) :
Device Type: Virtual I/O Ethernet Adapter (l-lan)
Hardware Address: 86:1f:e3:5f:21:04

Transmit Statistics:                          Receive Statistics:
--------------------                          -------------------
Packets: 1054                                 Packets: 0
Bytes: 63240                                  Bytes: 0
Interrupts: 0                                 Interrupts: 0
Transmit Errors: 0                            Receive Errors: 0
Packets Dropped: 0                            Packets Dropped: 0
                                              Bad Packets: 0

Max Packets on S/W Transmit Queue: 0         
S/W Transmit Queue Overflow: 0
Current S/W+H/W Transmit Queue Length: 0

Broadcast Packets: 0                          Broadcast Packets: 0
Multicast Packets: 0                          Multicast Packets: 0
No Carrier Sense: 0                           CRC Errors: 0
DMA Underrun: 0                               DMA Overrun: 0
Lost CTS Errors: 0                            Alignment Errors: 0
Max Collision Errors: 0                       No Resource Errors: 0
Late Collision Errors: 0                      Receive Collision Errors: 0
Deferred: 0                                   Packet Too Short Errors: 0
SQE Test: 0                                   Packet Too Long Errors: 0
Timeout Errors: 0                             Packets Discarded by Adapter: 0
Single Collision Count: 0                     Receiver Start Count: 0
Multiple Collision Count: 0
Current HW Transmit Queue Length: 0

General Statistics:
-------------------
No mbuf Errors: 0
Adapter Reset Count: 0
Adapter Data Rate: 20000
Driver Flags: Up Broadcast Running 
        Simplex Promiscuous AllMulticast 
        64BitSupport ChecksumOffload DataRateSet 

Virtual I/O Ethernet Adapter (l-lan) Specific Statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------
RQ Length: 4545
Trunk Adapter: True
  Priority: 1  Active: True
Filter MCast Mode: False
Filters: 255
  Enabled: 0  Queued: 0  Overflow: 0
LAN State: Operational

Hypervisor Send Failures: 1054
  Receiver Failures: 1054
  Send Errors: 0
Hypervisor Receive Failures: 0

Invalid VLAN ID Packets: 0

ILLAN Attributes: 0000000000003103 [0000000000003103]

Port VLAN ID:     2
VLAN Tag IDs:  None


Switch ID: ETHERNET0
Switch Mode: VEB
Management VLAN: Disabled

Hypervisor Information  
  Virtual Memory        
    Total (KB)                 80
  I/O Memory            
    VRM Minimum (KB)          100
    VRM Desired (KB)          100
    DMA Max Min (KB)          128

Transmit Information    
  Transmit Buffers       
    Buffer Size             65536
    Buffers                    32
    History             
      No Buffers                0
  Virtual Memory        
    Total (KB)               2048
  I/O Memory            
    VRM Minimum (KB)         2176
    VRM Desired (KB)        16384
    DMA Max Min (KB)        16384

Receive Information     
  Receive Buffers        
    Buffer Type              Tiny    Small   Medium    Large     Huge
    Min Buffers               512      512      128       24       24
    Max Buffers              2048     2048      256       64       64
    Allocated                 512      512      128       24       24
    Registered                512      512      128       24       24
    History             
      Max Allocated           512      512      128       24       24
      Lowest Registered       512      512      128       24       24
  Virtual Memory        
    Minimum (KB)              256     1024     2048      768 1536
    Maximum (KB)             1024     4096     4096     2048     4096
  I/O Memory            
    VRM Minimum (KB)         4096     4096     2560      864     1632
    VRM Desired (KB)        16384    16384     5120     2304     4352
    DMA Max Min (KB)        16384    16384     8192     4096     8192

I/O Memory Information  
  Total VRM Minimum (KB)    15524
  Total VRM Desired (KB)    61028
  Total DMA Max Min (KB)    69760
```

### CLIENTA

```
# entstat -d ent2
-------------------------------------------------------------
ETHERNET STATISTICS (ent2) :
Device Type: 
Hardware Address: 86:1f:e4:6d:3d:05
Elapsed Time: 0 days 2 hours 44 minutes 8 seconds

Transmit Statistics:                          Receive Statistics:
--------------------                          -------------------
Packets: 0                                    Packets: 0
Bytes: 0                                      Bytes: 0
Interrupts: 0                                 Interrupts: 0
Transmit Errors: 71                           Receive Errors: 0
Packets Dropped: 71                           Packets Dropped: 0
                                              Bad Packets: 0
Max Packets on S/W Transmit Queue: 0         
S/W Transmit Queue Overflow: 0
Current S/W+H/W Transmit Queue Length: 0

Broadcast Packets: 0                          Broadcast Packets: 0
Multicast Packets: 0                          Multicast Packets: 0
No Carrier Sense: 0                           CRC Errors: 0
DMA Underrun: 0                               DMA Overrun: 0
Lost CTS Errors: 0                            Alignment Errors: 0
Max Collision Errors: 0                       No Resource Errors: 0
Late Collision Errors: 0                      Receive Collision Errors: 0
Deferred: 0                                   Packet Too Short Errors: 0
SQE Test: 0                                   Packet Too Long Errors: 0
Timeout Errors: 0                             Packets Discarded by Adapter: 0
Single Collision Count: 0                     Receiver Start Count: 0
Multiple Collision Count: 0
Current HW Transmit Queue Length: 0

General Statistics:
-------------------
No mbuf Errors: 0
Adapter Reset Count: 0
Adapter Data Rate: 20000
Driver Flags: Up Broadcast Running 
        Simplex 64BitSupport ChecksumOffload 
        DataRateSet VIOENT 

# entstat -d ent1
-------------------------------------------------------------
ETHERNET STATISTICS (ent1) :
Device Type: Virtual I/O Ethernet Adapter (l-lan)
Hardware Address: 86:1f:e4:6d:3d:05
Elapsed Time: 0 days 2 hours 44 minutes 23 seconds

Transmit Statistics:                          Receive Statistics:
--------------------                          -------------------
Packets: 0                                    Packets: 0
Bytes: 0                                      Bytes: 0
Interrupts: 0                                 Interrupts: 0
Transmit Errors: 71                           Receive Errors: 0
Packets Dropped: 71                           Packets Dropped: 0
                                              Bad Packets: 0
Max Packets on S/W Transmit Queue: 0         
S/W Transmit Queue Overflow: 0
Current S/W+H/W Transmit Queue Length: 0

Broadcast Packets: 0                          Broadcast Packets: 0
Multicast Packets: 0                          Multicast Packets: 0
No Carrier Sense: 0                           CRC Errors: 0
DMA Underrun: 0                               DMA Overrun: 0
Lost CTS Errors: 0                            Alignment Errors: 0
Max Collision Errors: 0                       No Resource Errors: 0
Late Collision Errors: 0                      Receive Collision Errors: 0
Deferred: 0                                   Packet Too Short Errors: 0
SQE Test: 0                                   Packet Too Long Errors: 0
Timeout Errors: 0                             Packets Discarded by Adapter: 0
Single Collision Count: 0                     Receiver Start Count: 0
Multiple Collision Count: 0
Current HW Transmit Queue Length: 0

General Statistics:
-------------------
No mbuf Errors: 0
Adapter Reset Count: 0
Adapter Data Rate: 20000
Driver Flags: Up Broadcast Running 
        Simplex 64BitSupport ChecksumOffload 
        DataRateSet VIOENT 

Virtual I/O Ethernet Adapter (l-lan) Specific Statistics:
---------------------------------------------------------
RQ Length: 4545
Trunk Adapter: False
Filter MCast Mode: False
Filters: 255
  Enabled: 1  Queued: 0  Overflow: 0
LAN State: Operational

Hypervisor Send Failures: 0
  Receiver Failures: 0
  Send Errors: 0
Hypervisor Receive Failures: 0

Invalid VLAN ID Packets: 71

ILLAN Attributes: 0000000000003002 [0000000000003002]

Port VLAN ID:     2
VLAN Tag IDs:  None


Switch ID: ETHERNET0

Hypervisor Information  
  Virtual Memory        
    Total (KB)                 80
  I/O Memory            
    VRM Minimum (KB)          100
    VRM Desired (KB)          100
    DMA Max Min (KB)          128

Transmit Information    
  Transmit Buffers       
    Buffer Size             65536
    Buffers                    32
    History             
      No Buffers                0
  Virtual Memory        
    Total (KB)               2048
  I/O Memory            
    VRM Minimum (KB)         2176
    VRM Desired (KB)        16384
    DMA Max Min (KB)        16384

Receive Information     
  Receive Buffers        
    Buffer Type              Tiny    Small   Medium    Large     Huge
    Min Buffers               512      512      128       24       24
    Max Buffers              2048     2048      256       64       64
    Allocated                 512      512      128       24       24
    Registered                512      512      128       24       24
    History             
      Max Allocated           512      512      128       24       24
      Lowest Registered       512      512      128       24       24
  Virtual Memory        
    Minimum (KB)              256     1024     2048      768 1536
    Maximum (KB)             1024     4096     4096     2048     4096
  I/O Memory            
    VRM Minimum (KB)         4096     4096     2560      864     1632
    VRM Desired (KB)        16384    16384     5120     2304     4352
    DMA Max Min (KB)        16384    16384     8192     4096     8192

I/O Memory Information  
  Total VRM Minimum (KB)    15524
  Total VRM Desired (KB)    61028
  Total DMA Max Min (KB)    69760
```

### CLIENTB

Not yet configured

Comment: I am no seeing the part when you are plugging the virtual interfaces to the SEA. Pls show `entstat -d <sea iface>`. Off side q : did you set up single VIO for production env ? i would recommend dual VIO setup

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz - Is that not what the -vadapter bit of mkvdev -sea does? Will add me output when I get home.

Comment: you can include the interfaces while creating the sea, but as far as I can see you created them at the last step of your activities. Therefore I think you missed this step.

Comment: @KWubbufetowicz - output of `entstat` added for both VIO and client partition; thanks for looking

Comment: What is `ent5` interface ? At this moment I would do `chdev -dev ent10 -attr virt_adapters=ent11,ent12`. If the Vlans are correctly configured on the switch and ent9 is capable of caring vlan traffic it should work.

Comment: ent5 is one of the virtual adapters (there are 4 of these from ent4 to ent7). I wasn't sure whether these were supposed to align with the physicals (ent0 to ent3) or whether they were distinct. I have also tried using others. I will look into your chdev command shortly.

Comment: From what I remember on IVM it's slightly differently regarding ent4 to ent7 - those are default logical interfaces and cannot be really reconfigured or removed. You can check those via lshwres, same for other logical vlan adapters you create later: `lshwres -r virtualio --rsubtype eth --level lpar -F lpar_name:lpar_id:slot_num:state:ieee_virtual_eth:port_vlan_id:addl_vlan_ids:mac_addr:vswitch --header`
And from the entstat output, your SEA could only reach the outside world via VLAN 2, if ent5 would be an actual network adapter. Will add some links for more information ...

Answer (score 0):

For the VLAN part, and a general understanding of how VLAN tagging and Port VLAN ID works, and what the hypervisor does to such packets and what the SEA does, depending to what `addl_vlan_ids` ( short for additional VLAN IDs, which defines a VLAN trunk ) is configured for the SEA, best grab the presentation [A journey into the world of VLAN tagging and Virtual I/O!](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/cgaix/entry/a_journey_into_the_world_of_vlan_tagging_and_virtual_i_o2?lang=en) Although you will need Powerpoint for that, it cannot be opened with OpenOffice or LibreOffice sadly.

For more information on VLANs and SEA, see [Managing VLANs on mission-critical shared Ethernet adapters](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-managevlans/index.html?ca=drs-) which is referenced by [VLAN tagging and the VIOS: some questions and answers.](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/cgaix/entry/vlan_tagging_and_vios_questions_and_answers?lang=en)

And as you were asking for IVM in particular, please read through [IVM and VLAN Tagging](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/cgaix/entry/ivm_and_vlan_tagging1?lang=en) which also explains the difference between VLAN tagged packages and Port VLAN ID, and also shows the [`lshwres command`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/POWER7/p7hcg/lshwres.htm) `lshwres -r virtualio --rsubtype eth --level lpar` I mentioned in my comment.